# cannot show free space of SD card with arduino nano

Tags: sd-card

I'm using a nano v3, the SD module and a 64GB microSD card. 
Writing to the card works fine. 
But I can't print out the free space left on the card.

I'm using this code:

```
/*
  SD card read/write

 This example shows how to read and write data to and from an SD card file
 The circuit:
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13

 created   Nov 2010
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe

 This example code is in the public domain.

 */

#include <SPI.h>
//#include <SD.h>
#include "SdFat.h"
SdFat SD;

#define csPin 4
File myFile;
SdFat sd;

int startMillis;
int duration;

uint32_t freeKB;


void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(csPin)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (myFile) {
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("done.");
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}

void loop() {
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    myFile.println(j);
  }
  myFile.close();
  startMillis = millis();
  ShowFreeSpace();
  duration = millis() - startMillis;
  Serial.print("Took ");
  Serial.print(duration);
  Serial.println("ms to calculate");
  delay(1000);
}

void ShowFreeSpace() {
  // Calculate free space (volume free clusters * blocks per clusters / 2)
  long lFreeKB = sd.vol()->freeClusterCount();
  lFreeKB *= sd.vol()->blocksPerCluster()/2;

  // Display free space
  Serial.print("Free space: ");
  Serial.print(lFreeKB);
  Serial.println(" KB");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is a very poor description of what actually happens `can't print out the free space` ..... it provides no information that could be used to answer the question

Comment: aJazz, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have two instances of SdFat class. In setup() you `begin` the `SD` and for free space you try to use `sd`. Delete `SdFat sd;` line and in ShowFreeSpace use `SD.vol()`.